# How can I wait for a future to finish during a test if it wasn't called from the test directly?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dio

I'm trying to write a test for a method that makes a call to an API using [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). The Dio response has been mocked using [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter). My problem is that I need to wait for the API call to finish before continuing with the test, and I can't simply use await since the method I'm testing isn't asynchronous. Is there a way to wait for a future that wasn't called from the test?

Below is an example of what I'm talking about:

```dart
String apiResult = 'foo';

void methodToTest(){
  apiCall().then((value) => apiResult = value);
}
```

```dart
test('methodToTest works', () {
  expect(apiResult, equals('foo'));

  methodToTest();

  // I need to wait for apiCall to finish here.

  expect(apiResult, equals('bar'));
});
```

Previously, I have been able to use `Future.delayed(Duration.zero)` when I have had situations like this, but it has always seemed like a workaround, and now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the method I'm testing isn't asynchronous

Congratulations, your tests found a bug.

this is your method after fixing the bug:

```
Future<void> methodToTest() async {
  apiResult = await apiCall();
}
```

Comment: Sure, that works in this example. But what if you can't change it to be asynchronous. Or is that the only way? Maybe the is always possible in one way or another?

Comment: It is the easiest correct way. You could just wait for the time you think is the allowed maximum. If the value is not set *then*, it's an error. But that means your test will always take that much time, which is not feasable for multiple tests of this kind. You could change the function under test to implement some kind of signalling... but if you cannot even change it to async, implementing signalling in there is an impossible task, too.

Comment: Or you can check whether `apiResult` has changed every few milliseconds using a timer. That requires the value to actually *change*, so if the new `apiResult` is the same as the old one, you're stuck.